# declare variable in LinQ VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

How can I want to declare 'ResultType' outside For Each loop instead of declaring because I want to use the list result and join with another list?

[image]

```
For Each result In ResultContact
    ResultType = clsLogicAddress.SelectData_Address_ByAddrID(result.AddrId)
Next

'Dim ResultType = clsLogicAddress.SelectData_Address_byCustID(txtCustID.Text)
Dim ResultAddType = From tbl In clsLogicAddType.SelectCompanyType
Dim FilterContactByType = From a In ResultContact,
                               b In ResultType,
                               c In ResultAddType
                          Where a.AddrId = b.AddrId And
                                b.Type = c.RecId And
                                c.CompType = txtCompTypeHide.Text
                          Select a.ContactName, a.ContactId, c.CompType
```

Comment: Here is my code:

For Each result In ResultContact
                ResultType = clsLogicAddress.SelectData_Address_ByAddrID(result.AddrId)
            Next
            
            Dim ResultAddType = From tbl In clsLogicAddType.SelectCompanyType
            Dim FilterContactByType = From a In ResultContact, b In ResultType, c In ResultAddType Where a.AddrId = b.AddrId And b.Type = c.RecId And c.CompType = txtCompTypeHide.Text Select a.ContactName, a.ContactId, c.CompType

Comment: I have no real idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Are you wanting `Dim ResultType As List(Of SCIS.DC.a_ddress)`?

Comment: What is the return value of `SelectData_Address_ByAddrID`? `List(Of SCIS.DC.a_ddress)` or `SCIS.DC.a_ddress`?